# wanted a vb.net datagridview equivalent in python

Tags: python, tkinter, datagridview

I am learning python and using the 3.9 version with tkinter. I can connect to a sql server database and do all of the crud operations. However I would like be able to display the content of a table in tabular form as it is done with a datagridview in vb and c#. I am kind of confused. I couldnt find an example on the internet. I will appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad. Tkinter has a widget for showing rows and columns of data, and it's possible to create your own table out of labels or entry widgets. It's not clear why neither of those solutions would work for you.

Comment: OK. What's the name of tkinter widget that does the job? Thanks.

Comment: `ttk.Treeview`.